# configuring MVC files on MAMP, what is the server root?

Tags: php, indexing, url-routing

I'm working through this MVC tutoria: http://johnsquibb.com/tutorials/mvc-framework-in-1-hour-part-one and I'm trying to configure the index file. It asks for the following code:

```
<?php

/**
* WEB_ROOT_FOLDER is the name of the parent folder you created these 
* documents in.
*/
define('SERVER_ROOT' , '/var/www/WEB_ROOT_FOLDER');

//yoursite.com is your webserver
 define('SITE_ROOT' , 'http://yoursite.com');
```

It also has the following info:

> For the remainder of this article, we are going to assume the following server layout:
>
> web root: /var/www/
>   domain name: http://www.yourdomain.com

What is the difference between my `SERVER_ROOT` my `WEB_ROOT_FOLDER` and my `SITE_ROOT`?

If you couldn't already tell, I'm a total n00b, so try to be patient.

Answer (score 0):

The `SERVER_ROOT` is going to be the absolute path on the filesystem to directory the site is served from. In terms of Apache this is commonly referred to as the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

The `SITE_ROOT` its the base URL of the site.

Comment: At the risk of sounding very thick, I thought the path to the site directory was the same thing as the `site root`.  If you could elaborate it would be very helpful.

Comment: `SITE_ROOT` is a URL. When the web server recieves a request for this URL it loads the appropriate file from the filesystem to generate its response. This file can potentially live anywhere. You configure the web server in order to specify this location. In some case the two can be interchangeable but not always, and its better to pretend like they never are :-)

Comment: so, if site root is `http://localhost` is my `SITE_ROOT` is my `SERVER_ROOT` `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`?